# In iOS are there some multi-threaded component by design?

Tags: ios, multithreading

In other words: are there some component in iOS that runs in a multithreaded-way by design?

For Example:
i use a `Type A Object` to do some stuff, and iOS implements it in more than one thread.

I'm interested in any type of iOS component.
I need for a didactical purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As asked, no. There's no simple "do some stuff on more than one thread" object. However, there are classes like `OperationQueue` that you can use to add multiple units of work (`Operation` objects) that will run concurrently.